# Problema al ejecutar queries MySQL consecutivos en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Quiero insertar registros en una tabla desde otra tabla.
El primer registro a insertar es el registro que tiene la suma de los importes de los registros de la tabla origen. (Cargo)
Y el resto de registros a insertar son los que aparecen en la tabla origen (Abonos).

Solamente se ejecuta el primer query, insertando el registro correspondiente.

Tengo esto:

```
$BD = new ConexionDB();
$libro = 10
$asiento = ObtenerMaxAsiento();

//---------- CARGO
$sql = "SET @id = (SELECT max(id) from tabla);
SET @total = (SELECT SUM(importe) from temporal WHERE cruza_cod = 'X');
INSERT INTO tabla (id, libro, asiento, correlativo, periodo, importe)
VALUES (@id:=@id+1, $libro, $asiento, 1, $periodo, @total)";
$sth = $BD->query($sql);

//funcion obtiene maximo id
$id = ObtenerMax();

//---------- ABONO
$sql = "INSERT INTO tabla (id, libro, asiento, correlativo, periodo, importe) 
SELECT @id:=@id+1 as id, $libro, $asiento, @corr:=@corr+1 as corr, periodo, importe
FROM (SELECT @id:= $id) r, (SELECT @corr:=1) s, temporal WHERE cruza_cod='X'";
$sth = $BD->query($sql);
```

Al ejecutar me muestra:

> error de Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while
>   other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using
>   PDOStatement::fetchAll(). Alternatively, if your code is only ever
>   going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting
>   the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute

Mi conexión a la base de datos MySQL es con PHP/PDO.

```
class ConexionDB extends PDO {
    public function __construct () {
        try {
            parent:: __construct('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_DATA.';charset=utf8', DB_USER, DB_KEY);
            parent:: setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            die ('La Base de Datos no existe');
        }
    }

    function __destruct(){
    }
}
```

Lo ejecuto en Xampp 1.8.2
Cuál es el problema?DS

Comment: falta una especie de commit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probablemente el método `query` no sea el indicado para lo que quieres hacer. El buffer queda abierto mientras no hagas fetch. Yo te recomendaría usar `execute` y/o usar explícitamente `closeCursor`

```
//---------- CARGO
$sql1 = "SET @id .... ";
$sth = $BD->prepare($sql1);
$sth->execute();
$sth->closeCursor();

//funcion obtiene maximo id
$id = ObtenerMax();

//---------- ABONO
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO tabla ... ";
$sth = $BD->prepare($sql2);
$sth->execute();
$sth->closeCursor();
```

puede que `closeCursor` esté de más. Depende en parte de los parámetros de conexión que hayas pasado, o de los parámetros opcionales que le pases al execute. Por ejemplo

```
 $sth = $BD->prepare($sql2, [PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => false]);
```

Cerraría automáticamente el cursor luego de la ejecución.

Comment: Por el momento lo solucioné con __closeCursor()__ pero creo que tendré que utilizar Bindparam() para poder pasar los valores.

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que pdo no ejecuta múltiples instrucciones en una.
para eso debes usar `mysqli->multi_query` http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php

Cambia:

```
SET @id = (SELECT max(id) from tabla);
SET @total = (SELECT SUM(importe) from temporal WHERE cruza_cod = 'X');
INSERT INTO tabla (id, libro, asiento, correlativo, periodo, importe)
VALUES (@id:=@id+1, $libro, $asiento, 1, $periodo, @total)
```

por:

```
INSERT INTO tabla (id, libro, asiento, correlativo, periodo, importe)
VALUES ((SELECT max(id) from tabla), $libro, $asiento, 1, $periodo, (SELECT SUM(importe) from temporal WHERE cruza_cod = 'X'))
```